# MySQL fast check if hash exists

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, combinations, permutation

I'm trying to create a MySQL function which takes `n` and `m` as input and generates random `n` unique combinations of `m` ids from result of query.

The function will return *one* combination per call, and that combination must be distinct from all previous combinations.

During generation it must check another table: if combination already exists, to continue loop until every combination stays unique. Return combination as dash separated ids or if there is no room for unique combination to return false.

So I'm getting 100 random items like this:

```
SELECT
    `Item`.`id`
FROM
    `Item`
LEFT JOIN `ItemKeyword` ON `Item`.`id` = `ItemKeyword`.`ItemID`
WHERE
    (`Item`.`user_id` = '2')
AND(`ItemKeyword`.`keywordID` = 7130)
AND(`Item`.`type` = 1)
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 100
```

Past combinations are stored as md5 of concatenation of `itemID`s by `-`.

So I need to concatenate result of this query by `-` and create md5 of it. Then to send another query into second table named `Combination` and check with `hash` column if it exists or not. And continue this loop until I get `n` results.

I can't figure out how to achieve this correctly and fast. Any suggestion?

Update:

Whole SQL Dump is here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e5eb3bf1a10f9d762cc20a8146acf866

Comment: Do you really need the hash? Seems like unnecessary overhead to me. Just use a unique index over two columns in the `Combination` table.

Comment: @fancyPants now imagine concatenation of 100 numbers with at least 5 digits also 100 dashes between them. don't you think that md5 is better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Permutations**

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS unique_perm;

DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION unique_perm()
    RETURNS VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET ascii
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN
SET @n := 0;
iterat: LOOP
    SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(
             GROUP_CONCAT(province ORDER BY RAND() SEPARATOR '-'),
             '-', 3) INTO @list   -- Assuming you want M=3 items
        FROM world.provinces;
    SET @md5 := MD5(@list);
    INSERT IGNORE INTO md5s (md5) VALUES (@md5);  -- To prevent dups
    IF ROW_COUNT() > 0 THEN  -- Check for dup
        RETURN @list;       -- Got a unique permutation
    END IF;
    SET @n := @n + 1;
    IF @n > 20 THEN
        RETURN NULL;    -- Probably ran out of combinations
    END IF;
END LOOP iterat;
END;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Output:

```
mysql> SELECT unique_perm(),  unique_perm(),  unique_perm()\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
unique_perm(): New Brunswick-Nova Scotia-Quebec
unique_perm(): Alberta-Northwest Territories-New Brunswick
unique_perm(): Manitoba-Quebec-Prince Edward Island
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Notes:

- I hard-coded M=3; adjust as needed.  (It could be passed in as an arg.)
- Change column and table names for your needs.
- With out the test on @n, you could get in a loop if you run out of combinations.  (However, if N is even modestly large, that is 'impossible', so you could remove the test.)
- If the M is large enough, you will need to increase `@@group_concat_max_len`.  Also, the `RETURNS`.
- `CREATE TABLE md5s ( md5 CHAR(32) CHARACTER SET ascii PRIMARY KEY ) ENGINE=InnoDB` is needed.  And, you will need to `TRUNCATE md5s` between batches of calls to this function.
- That is a working example.
- Flaw:  It gives unique *permutations*, not unique *combinations*.  If that is not adequate, read on...

**Combinations**

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS unique_comb;

DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION unique_comb()
    RETURNS VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET ascii
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN
SET @n := 0;
iterat: LOOP
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(province ORDER BY province SEPARATOR '-') INTO @list
        FROM ( SELECT province FROM world.provinces
                  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2 ) AS x;   -- Assuming you want M=2 items
    SET @md5 := MD5(@list);
    INSERT IGNORE INTO md5s (md5) VALUES (@md5);  -- To prevent dups
    IF ROW_COUNT() > 0 THEN  -- Check for dup
        RETURN @list;       -- Got a unique permutation
    END IF;
    SET @n := @n + 1;
    IF @n > 20 THEN
        RETURN NULL;    -- Probably ran out of combinations
    END IF;
END LOOP iterat;
END;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Output:

```
mysql> SELECT unique_comb(),  unique_comb(),  unique_comb()\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
unique_comb(): Quebec-Yukon
unique_comb(): Ontario-Yukon
unique_comb(): New Brunswick-Nova Scotia
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Notes:

- The subquery adds some to the cost.
- Note that the items in each output string are now (necessarily) ordered.

Comment: @demonoid - your "m" is 100, so essentially no chance of running of permutations, or even combinations, so you could remove my use of @n and the extra `RETURN NULL`.  The `SELECT` in your Question replaces my 'x' subquery.

Comment: I don't quite get difference between results of first function and second one

Comment: So I need to copy all of existing combinations into md5's table?

Comment: The first will deliver both `Quebec-Yukon` and `Yukon-Quebec`; the second won't.  (See the definitions of "combination" and "permutations".)  The `md5s` table starts empty and builds up as you call the function -- M new rows per call.

Comment: I already have around 10 000 hashes. Do I need to copy them int new md5s table or just replace `#INSERT IGNORE INTO md5s (md5) VALUES (@md5);` with `SELECT count(*) FROM Combination WHERE Combination.hash = @md5;` ?

Comment: Second thing is, when I executed your first query I got `Error : Not allowed to return a result set from a function` error. what is problem?

Comment: Trying the `INSERT`, then checking Row_count is faster than using a `SELECT`.

Comment: The error comes from deviating from my sample code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138559/discussion-between-demonoid-and-rick-james).

Answer (score 3):

If you are testing for uniqueness via the md5, you need to sort the list before taking the md5.  This can be demonstrated with `SELECT MD5('1-2'), MD5('2-1');`

Get rid of `LEFT`, it seems useless.  After that, the Optimizer can choose between starting with `ItemKeyword` instead of `Item`.  (Without knowing the distribution of the data, *I* cannot say whether this might help.)

(It would be helpful if you provided `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.  In their absence, I will assume you are using InnoDB and have `PRIMARY KEY(id)` and `PRIMARY KEY(keywordID)`.)

'Composite' indexes needed:

```
Item: INDEX(user_id, type, id)
ItemKeyword: INDEX(ItemID, keywordID)
```

`ItemKeyword` smells like a many:many mapping table.  *Most* such tables can be improved, starting with tossing the `id`.  See [*7 tips on many:many*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) .

I am somewhat lost in your secondary processing.

[*My tips on RAND*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/random) may or may not be helpful.

**Schema Critique**

- A `PRIMARY KEY` is a `UNIQUE KEY` is an `INDEX`; eliminate redundant indexes.
- `INT(4)` -- the `(4)` means nothing; `INT` is always 32-bits (4 bytes) with a large range.  See `SMALLINT UNSIGNED` (2 bytes, 0..64K range).
- An MD5 should be declared `CHAR(32) CHARACTER SET ascii`, not 255, not utf8.  (`latin1` is OK.)
- The table `Combination` (id + hash) seems to be useless.  Instead, simply change `KEY md5 (md5) USING BTREE,` to `UNIQUE(md5)` in the table `Item`.
- You have started toward utf8mb4 with `SET NAMES utf8mb4;`, yet the tables (and their columns) are still `utf8`.  Emoji and Chinese need `utf8mb4`; most other text does not.

After addressing these issues, the original Question *may* be solved (as well as doing some cleanup).  If now, please add some further clarification.

**Minified**

*1.* Get a sorted list of `m` unique ids.  (I need "sorted" for the next step, and since you are looking for "combinations", it seems that "permutations" are not needed.)

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) AS list
    FROM (
        SELECT id FROM tbl
            ORDER BY RAND()
            LIMIT $m
         ) AS x;
```

*2.* Check for uniqueness.  Do this by taking `MD5(list)` (from above) and checking in a table of 'used' md5's.  Note:  Unless you are asking for a lot of combinations among a small list of ids, dups are unlikely (though not impossible).

*3.* Deliver the `list`.  However, it is a string of ids separated by commas.  Splitting this is best done in application code, not MySQL functions.

*4.* What will you do with the list?  This could be important because it may be convenient to fold step 4 in with step 3.

Bottom line:  I would do only step 1 and part of step 2 in SQL; I would build a 'function' in the application code to do the rest.

Comment: How to sort before taking MD5? I updated query, please take a look, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: And here is the dump: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e5eb3bf1a10f9d762cc20a8146acf866

Comment: I added some more.

Comment: Rick this is minified model of the problem. In fact `Combination` table has loads of other data. All that you mentioned will be fixed and they're not major problems for this issue. The main thing for me is to create a function which loops until finds n combinations of m ids from query response. Please try to help with main question. Thanks for your time. I appreciate it!

Comment: Made another stab.

Comment: Rick, the problem is, when I do it in application (currently I'm doing this way), as combinations' count grows in database, chance of duplication grows. So I need to take md5 and check with another query if combination is unique. So this process gets time-consuming because of checks and generation queries. Thats why I need this part to be done only inside MySQL. So, what I need is,  when I need 50 unique combinations of exact keyword, to do everything inside sql and return every combination as `-` separated strings. I still don't fully understand your answer.Can you please provide it as func?

Comment: Compromise?...  You do it in code (with supporting SQL statements); show us the code.  Time it.  Then I will try to convert that to a single Stored Proc (or close to such), and see if I can make it run faster.

Comment: Okay, lets not to talk about loop. Can you please show me how this function need to be to get one unique combination everytime when I call it? Answer have to be false (unique comb doesn't exist) or combination

Comment: Ah!  I missed that requirement.  I took the liberty of adding a paragraph to your Question to fold it in.  (If i got it wrong, please further edit your Question.)  (Back to scratching my head.)